# Shuffle array key and values php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to randomly shuffle the keys and values of a php array. I've already found solution to shuffle the order, but I want to shuffle the keys and values themselves.

The array `array('yes' => 'oui', 'no' => 'non', 'hello' => 'bonjour')` would for example become `array('oui' => 'yes, 'no' => 'non', 'bonjour' => 'hello')`. Note that the first and last value have randomly swapped key and value.

I know you can use `array_flip` to flip the keys and values in an array. But this flips **all** keys and values, while I want to randomly flip a few keys and values. How would I do this?

Comment: You can split the array into N arrays with random lengths, then do the array_flip on N-X of them and then merge them and shuffle the merged array once again?

Comment: may be, so: https://eval.in/900559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array('yes' => 'oui', 'no' => 'non', 'hello' => 'bonjour');

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if (0 === rand(0,1)) {
        $array[$value] = $key;
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array('yes' => 'oui', 'no' => 'non', 'hello' => 'bonjour');

// Run it in a foreach loop
foreach ($array as $key => $val){
    // rand(0, 1) will return either 0 or 1
    // It's up to you which value you want to set as anchor.
    if (rand(0, 1) === 0){
        // Set the value as key,
        // then set the key as value.
        $array[$val] = $key;

        // Delete the original one.
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```